# php form that requests data based on user select

Tags: php, forms

I have edited this based on help already received. I seem to be having issues with how the information is being called from the database. I keep getting errors of no results found so to speak. I think I got a pretty good idea what might be the cause, but I am not sure to rectify this.

Originally this search function was set up differently. I had an html page that had a dropdown list each option was assigned a value, this being text i.e.

```
<option Value="North East">North East</option>
```

However because I have separate tables in the database that control the population of the drop downs, the value is no longer being text but a number.

Any ideas on how to combat this?

This is currently what I have from head to toe.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
  <title>Results</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function()
  {
      $(".country").change(function()
      {
          var id=$(this).val();
          var dataString = 'id='+ id;

          $.ajax
          ({
              type: "POST",
              url: "ajax_city.php",
              data: dataString,
              cache: false,
              success: function(html)
              {
                  $(".city").html(html);
              } 
          });

      });
  });
  </script>
  <style>
  body {
      color: #FFFFFF;
  }
  #theclub{
      border:1px solid white;
      padding: 10px;
  }
  label
  {
      font-weight:bold;
      padding:10px;
  }
  </style>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style.css">
  <script type='text/javascript' src='style2.js'></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <label>Country :</label> <select name="country" class="country">
   <option selected="selected">--Select Country--</option>
   <?php
   include('db.php');
   $sql=mysql_query("select id,data from data where weight='1'");
   while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
   {
       $id=$row['id'];
       $data=$row['data'];
       echo '<option value="'.$id.'">'.$data.'</option>';
   } ?>
  </select>
  <label>City :</label> <select name="city" class="city">
   <option selected="selected">--Select City--</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Search" name="submit">
 </form>
 <?php
 if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] != ""){ } //--here is the condition that is true if search button is pressed
 $selectedOption = $_POST["city"];

 $result = mysqli_query($con,
 sprintf("SELECT * FROM `SouthYorkshire` WHERE  `EstProv` = '%s'",
 preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z ]/", '', $selectedOption))); 

 echo "<div id=\"Results\">";

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {
     echo "<div id=\"theclub\">";
     echo "<div class=\"ClubName\">";
     echo $row['EstName'];
     echo "</div><br>";
     echo "<div class=\"Location\">";
     echo $row['EstAddress2'];
     echo "</div>";
     echo "<br>";
     echo "<div id=\"website\"><a href=\"#\"><img src=\"photos/more-info.png\" width=\"75\" height=\"25\"/></a> <a href=\"" . $row['EstWebsite'] ."\" target=\"_blank\"><img src=\"photos/visit-website-button.png\" width=\"75\" height=\"25\" /></div></a></div>";
     echo "<br>";
 }
 echo "</div>";

 mysqli_close($con);
 ?>
 <br>
</body>
```

Comment: It's great that you wanted to share your own solution with others, but you should do that by posting an answer, not editing the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm shooting in the dark a bit because I'm not sure what you mean by first and second code...

If you want only one part of the code to run you need some sort of condition to check if to run it or not

If you don't want the second part of the code run right away you want to check if the post variable city is set and not empty and only run the code if the value isn't empty:

```
if(isset($_POST['city']) && $_POST['city'] != ""){
  // your code here
}
```

Comment: the first and second code was a refference in terms of the order i have displayed them on this site.i tried to use this option as well but i got back the following error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_BOOLEAN_AND, expecting ',' or ')' in /customers/b/6/d/herculesdjs.co.uk/FETCH.PHP on line 68

Comment: line 68 is this if(isset($_POST['city'] && $_POST['city'] != ''){

Comment: if(isset($_POST['city']) && $_POST['city'] != ""){
    
}

Comment: i have added the ) in but it still says the same thing

Comment: okay so i just copied in if(isset($_POST['city']) && $_POST['city'] != ""){ } and this stopped the error occurring on render of the page. However when i click search i still get the following errors:Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /customers/b/6/d/herculesdjs.co.uk/FETCH.PHP on line 73
Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in /customers/b/6/d/herculesdjs.co.uk/FETCH.PHP on line 77
Warning: mysqli_close() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /customers/b/6/d/herculesdjs.co.uk/FETCH.PHP on line 91

Comment: i have no idea what this means?

Comment: ok this means that you dont get a result back from your database... you gotta debug - prolly just a minor typo or so - the easiest way to find such a thing is to simply dump the values you're working with .. eg dump_var($selectedOption) and dump the sql statement take the dumped select and run it in the database

Comment: hmm maybe theres an issue with how the values from my dropdowns are being passed through. For example on my site i have North East selected in dropdown box 1, This calls for a list of cities in the database. The user then gets to select one of the cities. What ever they select needs to be passed on when user selects search

Comment: from my point i can only tell you that you have an error in your sql query - the only advice i can give you right now is to debug your code - a good way to do that is to simplify what you're trying to do - as said, try to dump the values you're working with - define a simple query and try if you get any results mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `SouthYorkshire` WHERE  `EstProv` like '%s'") - wich makes it easier to pinpoint the error and then you can put the complexity of the code back to where it has to go and prevent sql injection and everything else ...

Comment: Thank you for your help Maggz i managed to trace back the issue in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Your second code should be enclosed within a if condition in order to run it  after the first code exicution like the following way-

But first you have to add name attribute to your search button in first code-

```
<input type="submit" value="Search" name="submit">
```

and now your second code should be--

```
if($_POST['submit']) //--here is the condition that is true if search button is pressed
{
  $selectedOption = $_POST["city"];

$result = mysqli_query($con,
sprintf("SELECT * FROM `SouthYorkshire` WHERE  `EstProv` = '%s'",
    preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z ]/", '', $selectedOption))); 

echo "<div id=\"Results\">";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<div id=\"theclub\">";
echo "<div class=\"ClubName\">";
echo $row['EstName'];
echo "</div><br>";
echo "<div class=\"Location\">";
echo $row['EstAddress2'];
echo "</div>";
echo "<br>";
echo "<div id=\"website\"><a href=\"#\"><img src=\"photos/more-info.png\" width=\"75\" height=\"25\"/></a> <a href=\"" . $row['EstWebsite'] ."\" target=\"_blank\"><img src=\"photos/visit-website-button.png\" width=\"75\" height=\"25\" /></div></a></div>";
echo "<br>";
}
echo "</div>";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
}
```

Comment: I ave tried to do what you have put but doesn't seem to work, I just seem to get a bunch OF sql errors. the errors reffer's to sections that work perfectly well before hand. these are the errors: Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /customers/b/6/d/herculesdjs.co.uk/FETCH.PHP on line 74

Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in /customers/b/6/d/herculesdjs.co.uk/FETCH.PHP on line 78

Warning: mysqli_close() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /customers/b/6/d/herculesdjs.co.uk/FETCH.PHP on line 92